# I install ubuntu 13.10 but the Pc can't start up ubuntu it start with windows

Tags: windows-7, startup

I install ubuntu 13.10  but  the Pc can't  start up ubuntu it start with windows  .is there anything I should instal or do ?

Comment: try to add ubuntu boot loader in windows settings. or try to reinstall GRUB boot loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall GRUB loader. 
try this tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
from live CD

Answer (score 0):

If you have windows 8 preinstalled then first turn off the fast startup,after that while booting turn off the secure boot,,,then again while booting select the ubuntu from 2 os.